# More simplified way of creating page links dynamically?

Tags: php, object-oriented

A little birdie suggested I bring this question here, so here it goes.

Well I have a working script (see below) but it seems quite clunky and redundant; in my defense I wrote this code many moons ago, but that's not the point. I was curious if anyone has an idea on a more efficient way of writing this code, with less loops and conditionals and, well, noise in the code.

Code in question:

```
private function pageLinks($num, $page = 1, $search = false, $ne = false) {
    $query = ($search) ? '&query='.$search : null;
    $by = (is_numeric($ne)) ? '&by='.$ne : null;
    $links = 'Page(s):<a href="search.php?page=1' . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">1</a>';
    $count = 1;
    $npp = $this->numPerPage;
    $buttons = 9;
    $half = 4;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {
        if(($i%$npp) === 0) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    if($count < $buttons) {
        for($i = 2; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . $i . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
    } elseif($page <= ($half + 2)) {
        for($i = 2; $i <= $buttons; $i++) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . $i . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
        $links .= '...<a href="search.php?page=' . $count . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . $count . '</a>';
    } elseif($page <= ($count - ($half + 2))) {
        $links .= '...';
        for($i = $half; $i > 0; $i--) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($page - $i) . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . ($page - $i) . '</a>';
        }
        $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($page - $i) . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . ($page - $i) . '</a>';
        for($i = 1; $i <= $half; $i++) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($page + $i) . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . ($page + $i) . '</a>';
        }
        $links .= '...<a href="search.php?page=' . $count . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . $count . '</a>';
    } else {
        $links .= '...';
        for($i = $buttons - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $links .= '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($count - $i) . $query . $by . '" class="tableLink">' . ($count - $i) . '</a>';
        }
    }
    return($links);
}
```

The method is called like so:

```
$links = $this->pageLinks($count, $page, $url, $ne);
```

And the variables are as such:

`$count` = total number of clients in database `(int)`
`$page` = current page to build from `(int)`
`$url` = the name or email for the search `(String)`
`$ne` = is for the search string either by name (1) or email (2) `(int)`

And the output is something like (as links):

Page(s):`1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9`...`33`

Or if you're in the middle (page 20):

Page(s):`1`...`16` `17` `18` `19` `20` `21` `22` `23` `24`...`33`

Now this isn't always called through a search function, hence the default values for `$url` and `$ne`, but that's not very important. My question is there a cleaner way to handle building of these links? Or am I stuck with this cluster of loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$count = 1;
for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {
    if(($i%$npp) === 0) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
$count = floor($num / $npp) + 1;
```

As for the paging, I'd do it like this:

```
$from = $page - $half;
if ($from <= 2) $from = 2;
$to = $page + $half;
if ($to >= $count - 1) $to = $count - 1;

$extra = $query . $by;
$links = $this->pageLink(1, $extra);
if ($from > 2) $links .= "...";
for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++)
    $links .= $this->pageLink($i, $extra);
if ($i < $count) $links .= "..."; // I use $i instead of $to because $i == $to + 1, so I save one addition
$links = $this->pageLink($count, $extra);
```

Here, you also need:

```
private function pageLink($num, $extra) {
    return '<a href="search.php?page=' . $num . $extra . '" class="tableLink">' . $num . '</a>';
}
```

This was written by heart, so be weary of the possible bugs.

Comment: Genius! Works like a charm! Only bug was a missing `$` in the `pageLink` method, but that's the least of my worries. Wow, it's.. beautiful. Thank you, very informative and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I've fixed it. Thank you for that, and I'm glad I've been able to help.